# How to check validity of JWT to set refreshToken

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I'm using React and JWT + refresh token. When my user log in, I set in localStorage the token and refresh_token.

Now, I set up my token to 5s validity to make my logic for refresh token.

My question is, once my user is logged in, and the token and refresh token are stored in Local Storage, how can I check the validity on each reload or re-render of react ?

Am i supposed to make an API call on every page ?

Here is my loggin function :

```
// Login user
const login = async (userData) => {
    let datas;
    await axios.post('/authentication_token', userData)
        .then((response) => {
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data))
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Autorization'] = `Bearer ${response.data.token}`
            datas = response.data
        })
    return datas
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `refresh API` call in `App.js` and use `setInterval()` every 5 seconds to call your refresh token API, and your refresh token will be updated. Instead you should check the accuracy of the token, maybe if your token expires your API throw you 401 status code and you will be logged out.

let say this is your `App.js`

```
import React from 'react';


const App = () => {

  // get token from localStorage
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || '';
  setInterval(() => {
    // you need to check If have token then you call the API
    if (token) {
      try {
        // here you call refresh token API
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error)
      }
    }
  }, 5000);

  return (
    <></>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me understand the next step. Would you have an example ?

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can see the example :)